# Heat Map Tool Free

Tags: seo, analytics, click-tracking, demographics

From looking online, the free heatmap tools consistently mentioned are ClickHeat and ClickDensity.

`Heatmap.me` comes up second when searching `heatmap.me` but it is not mentioned much. What feedback is there on this service?

Comment: Unfortunately, product comparisons, reviews, and recommendations are considered off-topic for this site since they tend to lead to spam and promotional responses. You could ask for feedback in the chat room however.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that click-maps have only one use: to identify if people are attempting to click something unclickable.  All click-maps should provide this data.

They are often sold as if they can replace eye-tracking heat-maps.  However, look at where your mouse is now - I bet it is not over this text.  As such, it simply does not match where the eye is, and so does provide good usability information.

I believe it is against house rules to compare products here, so just try the free versions of both, but be aware that the data is usually pretty inaccurate.